# Why the styling is kept after re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styling

I am learning react and built a simple program that generates array and changing it's color. I don't understand why when I generate new array the color of the previous one is kept. I thought that happened because the state has changed when I generated a new array react will re-render the component and the color will be set back to default. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Dummy2 = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        generateArray();
    }, []);

    const generateArray = () => {
        const temp = [];
        for(let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            temp.push(i * 2);
        }
        setArr(temp);
    }

    const changeColor = () => {
        const arrayElements = document.getElementsByClassName('array-element');
        for(let i = 0; i < arrayElements.length; i++) {
            arrayElements[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="array-container">
                {arr.map((value, idx) => (
                    <div className="array-element"
                         key={idx}
                         style={{height: `${value}px`,
                                 weight: `${value}px`,
                                 margin: '1px 1px',
                                 backgroundColor: 'blue'}}
                    ></div>))
                }
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => changeColor()}>change-color!</button>
                <button onClick={() => generateArray()}>new-array</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dummy2;
```

**EDIT:** I manage to fix this by adding the following function

```
const resetColors = () => {
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-element');
        for(let i = 0; i < arrayBars.length; i++) {
            arrayBars[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        }
    }
```

I called it whenever the array is reset.

But still I don't understand why the styling is kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong way to go about doing it - Generally, in react all values that can change should be handled as state. And all values that affect a components styling should be passed as props to a component - As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid things like `getElementById` and `element.style =`. Instead pass this information via props.

Firstly, you can handle the color with `useState`, and then `setState` of that color when a button is clicked. Then the color value can be passed into the style prop of the div that you want to style.

```
const Dummy2 = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
    const [color, setColor] = useState("blue"); // Initialise color to "blue"

    /** -- snip -- **/

    const changeColor = () => {
        setColor("red"); // Set color here
    }

    return (
          /** -- snip -- **/
                    <div className="array-element"
                         key={idx}
                         style={{height: `${value}px`,
                                 weight: `${value}px`,
                                 margin: '1px 1px',
                                 backgroundColor: color, // pass in color here
                          }}
          /** -- snip -- **/
                <button onClick={() => changeColor()}>change-color!</button>
          /** -- snip -- **/
    );
}
```

If you wish to reset the color each time you generate an array, then you can call `setColor("<whatever color you want>")` inside of the `generateArray()` function. Then each time an array is generated, the color will be reset to that color.

As for why the styling is kept the same, it's because you are generating the same array each time. React is smart enough to know that it does not need to re-render a component/div that has the exact same values as the last render and so does not call a re-render.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. I have another unsolved question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408271/react-delay-on-visualization. Your answers are very comprehensive and helping me as a beginner to understand better the language. Can I notify you in the future about questions regarding react? if yes is there a way in stackoverflow to send you private message regarding questions I post?

Answer (score 1):

The React component is generally rerendered when it's state or props are changed.

So you should change your state to see the update.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Dummy2 = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
    const [color,setColor] = useState("blue");
    useEffect(() => {
        generateArray();
    }, []);

    const generateArray = () => {
        const temp = [];
        for(let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            temp.push(i * 2);
        }
        setArr(temp);
    };

    const changeColor = () => {   
         setColor("red");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="array-container">
                {arr.map((value, idx) => (
                    <div className="array-element"
                         key={idx}
                         style={{height: `${value}px`,
                                 weight: `${value}px`,
                                 margin: '1px 1px',
                                 backgroundColor: ${color}}}
                    ></div>))
                }
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => changeColor()}>change-color!</button>
                <button onClick={() => generateArray()}>new-array</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dummy2;
```

Comment: The `arr` in state is array of **numbers**. The `arrayElements` that I get in the `changeColor` function is array of **DOM elements**. I am not sure that changing the state like this with `setArr` is valid. Am I wrong?

Comment: In this case I think that because the `color` is part of the state when we change it to 'red' it still will be 'red' in the next render and wont change back to 'blue'. We can use `setColor('blue')` in the `generateArray` function to change to color back to default (in out case it is blue). What I am trying to understand is why when the re-rendering occurs the color does not changed back to 'blue' (in the case that the color is not part of the state).