# Why there is a delay on visualization?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, visualization

I am building a sorting visualization. I started with a simple bubble sort. When I sort a small array everything is fine and the visualization looks good no matter the speed, but when I visualize a large array there is a delay and the visualization seems to start a few steps ahead and not showing some of the first steps. Why is it happening?

This is my Code:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = 10;

const DEFAULT_COLOR = 'black';
const COMPARE_COLOR = 'darkred';
const DONE_COLOR = 'green';

const SPEED = 150;

const randomIntFromInterval = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

const Dummy = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
    const [numberOfElements, setNumberOfElements] = useState(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS);

    const timeout_id = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        generateArray();
    }, []);

    const reset = () => {
        resetColors();
        generateArray();
    }

    const generateArray = () => {
        const arr1 = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            arr1[i] = randomIntFromInterval(5, 100);
        }
        console.log(arr1);
        setArr(arr1);
    }

    const resetColors = () => {
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
        for(let i = 0; i < arrayBars.length; i++) {
            arrayBars[i].style.backgroundColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
        }
    }

    const bubbleSort = (arr, n) => {
        let i, j, temp, swapped, delay = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
            swapped = false;
            for(j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) 
            {
                createColor([j, j + 1], COMPARE_COLOR,  delay++);
                if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) 
                {
                    // swap arr[j] and arr[j+1] 
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                    createAnimation(j, j + 1, delay++);
                }
                createColor([j, j + 1], DEFAULT_COLOR, delay++);
            }
            createColor([n - i - 1], DONE_COLOR, delay++);

            // If no two elements were  
            // swapped by inner loop, then break 
            if(swapped === false) break;
        }

        const leftovers = [];
        for(let k = 0; k < n - i - 1; k++) {
            leftovers.push(k);
        }

        createColor(leftovers, DONE_COLOR, delay++);
    }

    const createAnimation = (one, two, delay) => {
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
        const id = setTimeout(() => {
            const barOneHeight = arrayBars[one].style.height;
            const barTwoHeight = arrayBars[two].style.height;
            arrayBars[two].style.height = `${barOneHeight}`;
            arrayBars[one].style.height = `${barTwoHeight}`;
        }, SPEED * delay);
        timeout_id.push(id);
    }

    const createColor = (indexes, color, delay) => {
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
        const id = setTimeout(() => {
            for(let i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
                arrayBars[indexes[i]].style.backgroundColor = color;
            }
        }, SPEED * delay);
        timeout_id.push(id);
    }

    const handleSort = (arr) => {
        bubbleSort(arr, arr.length);
    }

    const handlerRange = (e) => {
        setNumberOfElements(e.target.value);
    }

    const stopTimeOuts =() => {
        for(let i = 0; i < timeout_id.length; i++) {
            clearTimeout(timeout_id[i]);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="array-container">
                {arr.map((value, idx) => (
                    <div className="array-bar"
                         key={idx}
                         style={{
                            backgroundColor: DEFAULT_COLOR,
                            height: `${value}px`,
                            width: `${100 / arr.length}%`,
                            display: 'inline-block',
                            margin: '0 1px'
                         }}>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>

            <div className="buttons-container">
                <button onClick={() => handleSort(arr)}>Sort!</button>
                <button onClick={() => reset()}>Reset</button>
                <button onClick={() => stopTimeOuts()}>Stop!</button>
            </div>

            <div className="slider-container">
                1
                <input type="range" 
                       min="1" 
                       max="100" 
                       onChange={(e) => handlerRange(e)} 
                       className="slider" 
                       id="myRange" 
                />
                100
            </div>
            {numberOfElements}

        </div>
    );
}

export default Dummy;
```

**EDIT**: I don't know why but it seems that there are times that the delay occurs and there are times that it isn't. For now I still don't know why and how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Almost always when there are performance issues in React it has to do with component being  rendered multiple times.
Try to change useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        generateArray();
}, [NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good addition it made the array re-render when the slider is changed. Did you mean `numberOfElements` and not `NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS`. Regrading the performance issue this did help, there is still a delay at the start of the sorting.

Comment: Yes. "numberOfElements" will be more appropriate. I'll later try to go over the code and find the reason form the additional delay. If you find this answer useful please kindly mark it as useful answer. Thanks.