# Why elements are not in the right place while sorting?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, visualization

I am learning react and decided to try create a sorting visualizer. I started with bubble sort and pretty much succeeded creating a basic visualizer. I added the option to change the speed of the sorting and the length of the array that is sorted. I tested it a few times and what I found out is that sometimes when displaying the sorted array some elements are not in place. This can be seen when you have a tall element not in the place it should be (the array itself  behind the scene is sorted properly). So something happening to the display elements and I do not know what.
After the sorting is completed and if some of the elements are not in place, if I change the speed suddenly the elements jump back to where they suppose to be. I guess this is because the `speed` is part of the state and a re-redering is happeing.
What should I do to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = 10;

const DEFAULT_COLOR = 'white';
const COMPARE_COLOR = 'darkred';
const DONE_COLOR = 'green';

const SPEED = 4;

const SPEEDS = [1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300];

const randomIntFromInterval = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

const Dummy = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
    const [numberOfElements, setNumberOfElements] = useState(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS);
    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(SPEED);

    const timeout_id = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        generateArray();
    }, [numberOfElements]);

    const reset = () => {
        resetColors();
        generateArray();
    }

    const generateArray = () => {
        const arr1 = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            arr1[i] = randomIntFromInterval(5, 100);
        }
        console.log(arr1);
        setArr(arr1);
    }

    const resetColors = () => {
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
        for(let i = 0; i < arrayBars.length; i++) {
            arrayBars[i].style.backgroundColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
        }
    }

    const bubbleSort = (arr, n) => {
        let i, j, temp, swapped, delay = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
            swapped = false;
            for(j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) 
            {
                createColor([j, j + 1], COMPARE_COLOR,  delay++);
                if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) 
                {
                    // swap arr[j] and arr[j+1] 
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                    createAnimation(j, j + 1, delay++);
                }
                createColor([j, j + 1], DEFAULT_COLOR, delay++);
            }
            createColor([n - i - 1], DONE_COLOR, delay++);

            // If no two elements were  
            // swapped by inner loop, then break 
            if(swapped === false) break;
        }

        const leftovers = [];
        for(let k = 0; k < n - i - 1; k++) {
            leftovers.push(k);
        }

        createColor(leftovers, DONE_COLOR, delay++);
    }

    const createAnimation = (one, two, delay) => {
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
        const id = setTimeout(() => {
            const barOneHeight = arrayBars[one].style.height;
            const barTwoHeight = arrayBars[two].style.height;
            arrayBars[two].style.height = `${barOneHeight}`;
            arrayBars[one].style.height = `${barTwoHeight}`;
        }, SPEEDS[speed - 1] * delay);
        timeout_id.push(id);
    }

    const createColor = (indexes, color, delay) => {
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
        const id = setTimeout(() => {
            for(let i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
                arrayBars[indexes[i]].style.backgroundColor = color;
            }
        }, SPEEDS[speed - 1] * delay);
        timeout_id.push(id);
    }

    const handleSort = (arr) => {
        bubbleSort(arr, arr.length);
    }

    const handlerRange = (e) => {
        setNumberOfElements(e.target.value);
    }

    const stopTimeOuts =() => {
        for(let i = 0; i < timeout_id.length; i++) {
            clearTimeout(timeout_id[i]);
        }
    }

    const handleSpeed = (e) => {
        setSpeed(e.target.value);
    }

    const maxVal = Math.max(...arr);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="array-container" style={{height: '50%', backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
                {arr.map((value, idx) => (
                    <div className="array-bar"
                         key={idx}
                         style={{
                            backgroundColor: DEFAULT_COLOR,
                            height: `${(value * 100 / maxVal).toFixed()}%`,
                            width: `${85 / arr.length}%`,
                            display: 'inline-block',
                            margin: '0 1px'
                         }}>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>

            <div className="buttons-container">
                <button onClick={() => handleSort(arr)}>Sort!</button>
                <button onClick={() => reset()}>Reset</button>
                <button onClick={() => stopTimeOuts()}>Stop!</button>
            </div>

            number of elements: {numberOfElements}
            <div className="slider-container">
                1
                <input type="range" 
                       min="1" 
                       max="100" 
                       onChange={(e) => handlerRange(e)} 
                       className="slider" 
                       id="myRange" 
                />
                100
            </div>

            speed: {speed}
            <div className="slider-container">
                1
                <input type="range" 
                       min="1" 
                       max="10" 
                       onChange={(e) => handleSpeed(e)} 
                       className="slider" 
                       id="myRange" 
                />
                10
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Dummy;
```

Comment: Hey, glad it was solved. FYI, there is no need to tag the question with "solved", it's already displayed automatically once an answer has been accepted (which is done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the key inside of the div to be a unique identifier instead of `idx` - in this case you can use `value`:

```
/* -- snip -- */
<div className="array-bar"
     key={value}
/* -- snip -- */
```

This will stop react recycling each div with their respective indexes and instead re-render and re-order based on the new array.

The reason you see the unexpected behaviour is because react uses keys to identify each element. **So if you sort your array then apply an index as the id on render, react will get the element that was first rendered with that index as it's key and put it in that place.** By changing the key to a unique identifier, react does not get the elements mixed up (since the unique identifier never changes with respect to its element) and can now accurately render each item in the order you intend.

Example:
We render a list:

```
<div id=1>Foo</div> // Id "1" is now bound to this element
<div id=2>Bar</div>
```

So if you then reorder the list like this (note the id changes):

```
<div id=1>Bar</div> // this will be transformed to <div id=1>Foo</div>
<div id=2>Foo</div> // this will be transformed to <div id=2>Bar</div>
```

Then react will transform the elements into whatever id they were assigned to first - This is why it's important to have **unique identifiers**. You can generate a unique identifier via a library that generates uuids or other sufficiently random strings.

You can read more here: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Great answer! solved the problem for me, thanks. Regrading the `value` as key, I am not sure that it will be valid in this case because `value` is not necessarily unique in the array.

Comment: Right, but it still works since the only data in the divs in your example is the value. So two 10 values are exactly the same and should be in the same order (in your example). However if there was other data inside of your divs then you would probably want to generate a truly unique identifier such as a uuid for each div. I'll update my answer so this is more clear.

Comment: Again thank you for the help, I have another question in react maybe you could help me there too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62396091/react-styling-is-kept-after-re-rendering

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411951/unexpected-behavour-when-removing-an-item-from-an-array-in-react/62412342?r=SearchResults&s=43|0.0000#62412342